# Is possible to configure python to use full path with spaces?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I have question about vscode, venv and code runner

My setting looks like:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3"
"code-runner.executorMap": { "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName " }
```

as select interpreter I use `./venv/bin/python`

and on Terminal everything works

but `ctrl+alt+N` in OUTPUT I get: `/bin/sh: /Users/me/Documents/Visual: No such file or directory`

and should be

```
/Users/me/Documents/Visual Studio Code/MyProject/venv/bin/python
```

when I change to `/Users/me/Documents/VisualStudioCode/MyProject/venv/bin/python`     it works!!!

Is possible to configure python to use full path with spaces???

Thanks a lot

Tomasz

PS

what mean here -u?

```
("$pythonPath -u $fullFileName ")
```

Comment: @Ophir have You edited my qestion? I mean sugestion for formating my qestion or is it automatic?

Comment: it is problem with system, not Python. If you use spaces then you have to put path in `" "` or `' '` or you have to use \ before every space in name. BTW: Spaces always made problem in path and filename so older programmes never used spaces in names. The same problem made native chars - ąęść.

Comment: BTW: run `python --help` and you will see what means `-u`

Comment: @furas OK but where I should add the "" '' or \ ??? look please for my settings

Comment: around path inside your string - see `' '` in `"$pythonPath -u '$fullFileName'"` or `\" \"` in `"$pythonPath -u \"$fullFileName\""`

Comment: @furas nothing has changed :(

Comment: frankly, the simples solution is to rename folder and use without spaces `VisualStudioCode` - it resolves current and future problems. And in the future always keep this rule - `no spaces in file/folder names`

Comment: @furas I know. The question is "Is it possible with spaces?" ;)

Comment: it should be possible with spaces - but different systems work in different way. Some of them inside `" "` need `' '`, other `" "` because they don't change `$name` if it inside `' '`, other may need `\" \"` or `\\\" \\\"` to correctly use `" "` inside other `" "`

Comment: I've tried all and nothing :(

Comment: it seems you use MacOS - I don't use it so I can't check how it behave. And I don't know if you still get the same error - maybe it doesn't work but it gives different error message which could gives some clue how to use it. OR maybe you change it in one file but program use settings from different file and your changes are never used.

Comment: @furas Thanks. I created New Folder now, new venv, new file.py and I get /bin/sh: /Users/me/Documents/New: No such file or directory

Comment: and for example Google Drive created folder Google Drive on my disk and I can't create there any projects becouse I get error /Users/me/Google: No such file or directory

Comment: can't you rename it or change it in some settings? Probably you can create link to `Google Drive` with name i.e `GoogleDrive` and use this folder `GoogleDrive` in project. As for project probably you have to add `" "` to settings after creating project.

Comment: it doesn't work too, I can't do this.

Comment: I've found similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497103/code-runner-does-not-work-for-python-in-vscode

Comment: @furas Do You know anyone who has macOS and can chack this issue?

Comment: I don't know anyone with MacOS. Maybe you should go to some Visual Studio Code forum and ask useres or send it as issue.

Comment: @furas Hi how are you? I found the solution is in Answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {"python": "\"$pythonPath\" -u $fullFileName"}
```

Comment: BTW: you can also use `" "` inside `' '` - `' "$pythonPath" -u $fullFileName'` . Normally you can use also  `' '` inside `" "`  but shell/bash may tread `'$pythonPath'` as normal string and not replace `$pythonPath` with value.

Comment: @furas and it is very strange that on windows You should add  ' '  here: '$fullFileName' and on mac '$pythonPath'

Comment: to make sure I would add `' '` on both `'$fullFileName'` and `'$pythonPath'`. But I always try to use paths without spaces and native (Polish) chars.

Comment: @furas It is not easy do like this If you have path eg,                                  Users/Adam/My Documents/Python/ThisProject it doesn't work becouse error is on My Documents

Comment: do you have problem when you put it in `" "` inside `' '`  - `' "$pythonPath" -u "$fullFileName" '` ? It should create string `"/path/to/python" -u "Users/Adam/My Documents/Python/ThisProject"` and it should work in bash/shell. If variables are replaced by VS (not bash/shell) then should work also `' '` inside `" "` - `" '$pythonPath' -u '$fullFileName' "` and it should create string `'/path/to/python' -u 'Users/Adam/My Documents/Python/ThisProject'` and it should also work in `bash/shell`.

Comment: If some programs still make problem then I would create link to `My Document` without spaces - ie. `ln -s "Users/Adam/My Documents" Users/Adam/MyDocuments` and then I would use `Users/Adam/MyDocuments/Python/ThisProject` in these programs. And still use old path with spaces in other programs.