# Code Runner extension in VSCode in Ubuntu 20.04 platform is not working with python file

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Whenever I try to run the code `print(“Hello World”)` with Code Runner extension in VSCode in Ubuntu 20.04, it shows the output

```
Command ‘python not found’
```

[image]

But if I right-click in VSCode and choose “Run python file in terminal”, it runs smoothly but not through Code Runner extension.

Comment: Please don't post pictures, your output is text, you can just copy-paste it. Have you reviewed other similar questions on this topic? Try setting `code-runner.executorMap` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497103/code-runner-does-not-work-for-python-in-vscode

Comment: @soulshined Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings type `code runner executor map` click on edit in json. look for python. replace `python -u`  with `python3 -u`

Comment: by replacing the same the program in running but it is not taking input from keyboard input() method